# Gradle auto resolve dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

Does gradle automatically imports the dependencies of the dependencies?
For example in an Android application I have those:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    #######compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

okhttp and retrofit use Gson.

Do I have to include Gson manually or it is resolved by gradle automatically?
If I include Gson manually, does gradle imports the library twice and thus increasing my application size?

Comment: Each module have dependencies handled by their own build.gradle, therefore you don't have to add it's dependancies by yourself

Answer (score 1):

So far Retrofit itself used GSON and it should import the GSON dependencies automatically once you compile `'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'`.

When using Retrofit together with OkHttp, OkHttp (version 1.6.0 or newer) and OkHttp-UrlConnection is required.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
```